# how to pass bitmap to c++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, .net, pinvoke, native

The program has no tip errors ,But there is no any picture display in c++ form,Tested the simple data types, such as int, can be normal delivery,please give me  a simple example ,tell me what to do

C# Code

```
[DllImport("dllTestForm.dll", EntryPoint = "showFormC")]
static extern void testShowFormC(byte[] photo,int len);

private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(@"d:\1\1.jpg");

        Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bmp.Width, bmp.Height);
        System.Drawing.Imaging.BitmapData bmpData =
        bmp.LockBits(rect, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,bmp.PixelFormat);

        // Get the address of the first line.
        IntPtr ptr = bmpData.Scan0;

        // Declare an array to hold the bytes of the bitmap. 
        int bytes  = Math.Abs(bmpData.Stride) * bmp.Height;
        byte[] rgbValues = new byte[bytes];

         // Copy the RGB values into the array.
         System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(ptr, rgbValues, 0, bytes);

         // Unlock the bits.
         bmp.UnlockBits(bmpData);

         testShowFormC(rgbValues, bytes);
}
```

C++ Code

```
void __stdcall showFormC(byte *photo,int len)
{
    ThelloWorld *a=new ThelloWorld(Application); //winForm,display photo
    a->ImageEnView2->IO->LoadFromBuffer(photo,0,len);  
    a->Show();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried specifying the `StdCall` calling convention on your DllIimport?  I believe that the default is `WinApi`, and iirc that resolved to cdecl.  I would expect a stack imbalance though... so perhaps not. BTW, your example leaks. Can you sow us `LoadFromBuffer`?

Answer (score 0):

Buffer got from C# code is not completed.

You only get bitmap pixel data but not header. Header contains info to describe pixel data (8 bit, 16 bit, 24 bit, color palette and so on).

For `a->ImageEnView2->IO->LoadFromBuffer(photo,0,len);`, I guess you are using TImageEnIO component. From help http://www.imageen.com/help/ImageEn/TImageEnIO.LoadFromBuffer.html, why not pass whole jpeg file data to LoadFromBuffer ?

Comment: how to add the header info ?

Comment: Actually, it is hard to create header manually. It is better save jpeg image to bitmap (contains header), and pass bitmap buffer to c++ code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Bitmap.Save()` method to convert it to a memory stream and then send it to `C++ dll`.

```
image.Save(imageMemoryStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
```

Then, in `C++ dll` use decoding such as `cv::imdecode()` method to get the image.

Details are [here](https://github.com/sumsuddin/ImageProcessingOpenCV).